Were the Philistines Canaanites?
Were the Philistines Canaanites?
The https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Philistine
Says that they were: "of or relating to the people of ancient Philistia", not Canaan.

Now the Philistines gathered together their armies to battle...and Saul and the men of Israel were gathered together...And the Philistines stood on a mountain on the one side, and Israel stood on a mountain on the other side...And there went out a champion out of the camp of the Philistines named Goliath of Gath, whose height was six cubits and a span! (1 Samuel 17:1-4)

Were the Philistines just another tribe of Canaanites with a history of living in the land of Israel?

Note that names can refer to geographical areas, not only to nationalities. For instance, until relatively recently, Turks, Jews, Europeans, Arabs, and others that lived in the part of the Ottoman Empire known as Palestine were all called Palestinians, a name that has today come to mean one specific group. (In the 1960 movie Exodus, Paul Newman's character calls himself a "Palestinian Freedom Fighter", a Jew fighting for independence from the British.)

I think this is a question that is better suited for the hermeneutics site, but they require a biblical citation, so can you edit in which verse you're looking at about Philistines (guessing something from Judges or Kings?).

In the OT the Philistines are considered as distinct from the Canaanites - eg Judges 3:3, Joshua 13:1-5.
Their king in the days of both Abraham and Isaac was Abimelech, very likely meaning there was a dynasty of Abimelechs. I have read the suggestion that possibly "Abimelech" means "king". More likely, Abimelech means "Melech is my father". Melech is better known in the OT as "Molech". The king's name shows Dagon was not the only god they worshipped.
Verses of note are Genesis 26:16 where Abimelech says to Isaac "Depart from us, for you are much mightier than us".  The whole of Genesis 26 gives an account of the tensions between the Philistines and Isaac. What is most clear is that land was not privately owned, and the Philistines at that time were not all-powerful.
At the time of the Exodus from Egypt the Israelites were not led the Way of the land of the Philistines, also called outside the Bible, the Way of Horus, lest the people turn back to Egypt if they see a danger of war, Exodus 13:17.  They were not trained for war at all: as slaves they had learned that resisting armed men was pointless.  But who would be their adversary?  The Way of the land of the Phllistines, the northmost and shortest access route into Egypt from their chief enemies, the Hittites (and later Assyrians, Babylonians and Persians) was heavily defended by the Egyptians. There were bridges over the waterways and canal barriers with fortresses at these bridges to prevent two things: the enemy getting into Egypt, and slaves getting out.  It was fighting these Egyptian border fortifications that was the first and probably most significant fear. It does not necessarily mean that at this time the Philistines were especially a major force.
Amos 9:7 tells us the Philistines were mostly seen as coming from Caphtor, which is usually regarded as the island of Crete.
The "Peleset" were one of the ethnic groups making up what are called today the "Sea Peoples". It is common to associate the Peleset with the Philistines.  The Sea Peoples caused devastation in much of the Middle East.  It is believed the wars against them greatly depleted the coffers of the Pharaohs, which played a major part in bringing the New Kingdom era of Egypt (and Egyptian power) to an end.  (The Peleset might have been involved only with the "Sea Peoples" when they were attacking Egypt.)
They were a distinctive people with their own god, Dagon, a god represented by a statue with the head of a fish, and their own local area of the five cities in the Gaza region.  They were probably reliant quite heavily on fishing. They became dominant over the Israelites during the time of the Judges, with control of the superior technology in iron production.
And if the Peleset group of the Sea Peoples are the Philistines then their soldiers had their own distinctive helmets which look as if they were probably corrugated, maybe corrugated iron.

Following a couple links in the same dictionary, you'll see that Philistia
refers to the "southwestern part of ancient Palestine" and that Canaan is "sometimes used to refer to all of ancient Palestine". Geographically, at least, the Philistines were Canaanites (and this question is kind of like asking "are New Yorkers from New York or America"). Ethnically and culturally they were distinct from other Canaanite nations, they were relative latecomers to the region, apparently of Greek or Minoan origins. Wikipedia
